# How to Get full PLT Entry of a function and not the offset?

Tags: python, reverse-engineering

I am trying to leak libc's base address by first leaking the address of gets(). However, using Pwntools to get the PLT and GOT (and pretty much anything) entries only gives me their offsets as compared to the base address.

How should I get the actual address of the entries?

[image]